# How to create Dictionary inside Array structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create something like this in Swift

```
NSArray *array = 
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Xcode",@"IDE",@"iOS",@"language", nil],
        [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Eclipse",@"IDE",@"Java",@"language", nil]
    ,nil];
```

I surfed around and also referred https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_399 
but no luck. Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy as can be

```
let array = [["IDE": "Xcode", "language": "iOS"], ["IDE": "Eclipse", "language": "Java"]]
```

**PlayGround snap :**[image: PlayGround snap]

Comment: That was actually simple! Thanks a ton @eXhausted. Can you tell me what are the substitutes for objectAtIndex and
valueForKey?

Comment: `let array = [["IDE": "Xcode", "language": "iOS"], ["IDE": "Eclipse", "language": "Java"]]
let object = array[0]
println(object["IDE"])`

try this code to figure out

Comment: In case someone else is looking for creating multiple object/keys with NSDictionary: var eventDict = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: "value1", "key1", "value2", "key2")